# jsp error 404 when filters are added

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-404, web.xml

my application is working without filters. However, when I add filters in web.xml for remote desktop login I am getting error 404 " requested resource is not available" when i run my jsp. Can u please tell me the solution?

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   <filter>
          <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
          <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>principalFormat</param-name>
              <param-value>fqn</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>roleFormat</param-name>
              <param-value>both</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>allowGuestLogin</param-name>
              <param-value>true</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>securityFilterProviders</param-name>
              <param-value>
                   waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider
                   waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider
              </param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
              <param-value>
                   Negotiate
                   NTLM
              </param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider/realm</param-name>
              <param-value>WaffleFilterDemo</param-value>
          </init-param>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

Comment: Any errors in the log? Have you debugged it to see how the filter proceeds?

Comment: I have asked about errors **in the log**, i.e. Tomcat (or whatever servlet container you use) log.

Comment: Hey the problem was solved when I added waffle dependency.The dependency i added was:                                                                                 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.dblock.waffle</groupId>
    <artifactId>waffle-jna</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>